# How to add a "confirm delete" option in ASP.Net Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to add a "confirm delete" option in ASP.Net Gridview ?

Comment: where you want to add "confirm delete" option in inside gridview button or outside gridview?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This should do it.

I found it here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1331581/2678206.aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/site/img/icons/cross.png"
                    CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?');"
                    AlternateText="Delete" />               
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: If you don't want to use an image, then you can just as easily use a LinkButton instead of an ImageButton as shown in the solution from @Saksham-Gupta below

Answer (score 30):

If your `Gridview` used with `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"` , you may convert it to `LinkButton`:

1. Click **GridView Tasks** and then **Edit Columns**. 
   [image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/32784002@N02/15395933069/]
2. Select **Delete** in **Selected fields**, and click on **Convert this field into a TemplateField**.      Then click **OK**: 
   [image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/32784002@N02/15579904611/]
3. Now your `LinkButton` will be generated. You can add `OnClientClick` event to the `LinkButton` like this:
   `OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'); "`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "Convert this field into a TemplateField" functionality, I can see this being really useful in the future.

Answer (score 14):

I did this a bit different. In my gridview I set the `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"`. To find the delete button I use jQuery and add a click event to the found Anchors.

```
jQuery("a").filter(function () {
        return this.innerHTML.indexOf("Delete") == 0;
        }).click(function () { return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"); 
});
```

This is quick and simple for what I need to do. Just be mindful that Every Anchor in the page that displays Delete will be selected by jQuery and will have the event added to it.

Comment: Works nicely. You can improve things further by adding a more specific selector to look for anchors within the grid if you need it.

Answer (score 7):

I like this way of adding a confirmation prompt before deleting a record from a gridview. This is the CommandField definition nested within a GridView web control in the aspx page. There's nothing fancy here--just a straightforward Commandfield.

```html
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" UpdateText="Save" ShowDeleteButton="True">
  <ControlStyle CssClass="modMarketAdjust" />
</asp:CommandField>
```

Then, all I had to do was add some code to the RowDeleting event of the GridView control. This event fires *before* the row is actually deleted, which allows you to get the user's confirmation, and to cancel the event if he doesn't want to cancel after all. Here is the code that I put in the RowDeleting event handler:

```js
Private Sub grdMarketAdjustment_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles grdMarketAdjustment.RowDeleting
  Dim confirmed As Integer = MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to delete this market adjustment?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground, "Confirm Delete")
  If Not confirmed = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    e.Cancel = True 'Cancel the delete.
  End If
End Sub
```

And that seems to work fine.

Comment: @statmaster's answer is preferable to this one. First, you only need to put code in the aspx page (this one requires code in both the aspx page and the code-behind page). Second, MsgBox is required for this solution, and it may not work on a web server. You could still use ScriptManager to display an alert in the code-behind, instead of using MsgBox, and it would work both in Visual Studio and on the web server. But why not just use the simpler solution which doesn't require any code in the code-behind?

Comment: what if I need the confirm massage from server side ? i.e. For different languages support . @statmaster solution doesnt work with `<% %>`

Answer (score 5):

I didn't want any image so i modified the answer given by @statmaster to make it simple entry along with the other columns.

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');">Delete </asp:LinkButton>             
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The colour of the text can be changed using the Forecolor Property.

Comment: This is the simplest way to delete with confirmation in a gridview

Answer (score 4):

You can do using OnClientClick of button.

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('confirm delete')"
```

Comment: There is no OnClientClick event for button. You can add OnClientClick for a LinkButton

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

I used for *Update* and *Delete* buttons. It doesn't touch *Edit* button. You can use auto generated buttons.

```
  protected void gvOperators_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;
        var updateButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        if (updateButton.Text == "Update")
        {
            updateButton.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you really want to update?');";
        }
        var deleteButton = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2];
        if (deleteButton.Text == "Delete")
        {
            deleteButton.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I quite like adding the code in the `GridView` `RowDataBound` event to inform  the user exactly which item they are trying to delete. Slightly better user experience?

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lnkBtnDelete = e.Row.FindControl("lnkBtnDelete") as LinkButton;

        // Use whatever control you want to show in the confirmation message
        Label lblContactName = e.Row.FindControl("lblContactName") as Label;

        lnkBtnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the contact {0}?');", lblContactName.Text));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my preferred method. Pretty straight forward:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewConfirmDelete.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Although many of these answers will work, this shows a straightforward example when using CommandField in GridView using the OnClientClick property.

ASPX:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"... >
<Columns>
<!-- Data columns here -->
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.CS:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex != GridView1.EditIndex)
    {
        (e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[2] as Button).OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems getting a commandField Delete button to honor the 'return false' response to when a user clicked cancel on the 'Are you sure' pop-up that one gets with using the javascript confirm() function. I didn't want to change it to a template field.

The problem, as I see it, was that these commandField Buttons already have some Javascript associated with them to perform the postback. No amount of simply appending the confirm() function was effective.

Here's how I solved it:

Using JQuery, I first found each delete button on the page (there are several), then manipulated the button's associated Javascript based on whether the visitor agreed or canceled the confirming pop-up.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

               $('input[type="button"]').each(function() {

                   if ($(this).val() == "Delete") {
                       var curEvent = $(this).attr('onclick');
                       var newContent = "if(affirmDelete() == true){" + curEvent + "};" 
                       $(this).attr('onclick',newContent);                       
                   }
               });
}

function affirmDelete() {    
               return confirm('Are you sure?');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine for me.

```
jQuery("a").filter(function () {
        return this.innerHTML.indexOf("Delete") == 0;
        }).click(function () { return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I love the JavaScript solution and have some updates to work with dynamic ajax loading:

```
     $(document).on("click", "a", function () {
        if (this.innerHTML.indexOf("Delete") == 0) {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
        }
    });
```

Hope it help ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is my method and it works perfectly.

asp

```
 <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ItemStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="color" HeaderText="Edit"
                                EditText="<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #27ae60;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-edit'></span></span>"
                                DeleteText="<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #c0392b;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-bin'></span></span>"
                                CancelText="<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #c0392b;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-remove-2'></span></span>" 
                                UpdateText="<span style='font-size: 20px; color: #2980b9;'><span class='glyphicons glyph-floppy-saved'></span></span>" />
```

C# (replace 5 with the column number of the button)

```
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {

        }
        else {
            ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[5].Controls[2]).OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');";

        }
```