# Asking for a confirmation with conditions

Tags: asp.net, confirmation

How do I ask for a confirmation when an event fire, only under certains conditions ? I'm working on the server side and I want to ask for a confirmation only if my boolean is true.

Comment: What kind of confirmation, can you explain it more clearly? For me most of time i use javascript confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to add a "confirm delete" option in ASP.Net Gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793955/how-to-add-a-confirm-delete-option-in-asp-net-gridview)

Ok lets say you do have a grid with a button inside template column

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return check();" />
```

and write in your check function determine if button should raise a postback?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function check() {

  var doINeedToAskUserConfirmation =  // Get this according to your needs
  if ( doINeedToAskUserConfirmation  ){
      return confirm("Are you sure?");
  }
  return true;
}

</script>
```

lets say you have a button

```
<input type="button" id="btnConfirm" value="Proceed"/>
```

Make an ajax call to determine if you need any confirmation.

```
$("#btnConfirm").click(function(){

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "some.ashx",
     data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
  }).done(function( response ) {
     // lets say when response is true we will ask confirmation
     if ( msg )
     {
        var c = confirm( "All record will be deleted. Are you sure ? ");
        // Do another ajax call to complete your operation
     }
  });


});
```

Comment: You'll need JQuery for this solution.

Comment: I feel bad to say it but, the enterprise where I'm working, do not allow me to use AJAX ...

Comment: @citronas yes I dont know this will work for OP. He can also do this kind of logic without JQuery.

Comment: @GmodCake no ajax ? I assume no javascript also ?

Comment: @adt Javascript : ok
     AJAX : no I can't tell you why, it's my first mounts in this entreprise

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of you events you are using, you could create a class that derives from `EventArgs` and place your condition as a property (and call it MyCondition for instance) in your own class.

In the eventhandling method, you can then use

```
if(e.MyCondition)
{
  // do something
}
```

**Edit**:
Based on you comments, I'd suggest you try to use a [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx) for Editing, or use the GridViews Editmode if you like.
You may also take a look at the [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

Comment: hum, it look way too hard for what I'm doing, I want to ask for a save confirmation, is there a easier way to do it ?

Comment: Hmm you said server-side. Save confirmation indicates client-side interaction.

Comment: I can work on both, I just need to get the response of the confirmation on the server-side ...

Comment: Are you talking about a control, like a checkbox and server-side validation that validates if the checkbox is actually checked?

Comment: I'm working with a aspxgridview, when the user select a row, the content of the row is loaded in some textbox, when he modify one of them, a boolean named EditorMode change to "true" and if it is true, when somethings else happen, a confirmation message shows up, and I want to get the answer given from this confirmation message on the server-side

Comment: Sorry for my horrible english, i'm a french canadian

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you call a confirmation message. A confirmation message sound like a read-only text for me, that you are creating on the server side. I'll post you two links to the MSDN, that I think could help

Comment: I'm talking of a pop-up that says "Are you sure you want to ... ?" and I want to know if he answered "Yes" or "No"