# how to delete a row on gridview with a JavaScript button and remain on the same page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am displaying a set of records through gridview, and `edit` and `delete`
 buttons next to them.  I am having a problem in the record deletion section.  The behavior I want is the following: the user clicks the button, a JavaScript validation function is called and after the button click the records are deleted, but the user remains on the same page with the rest of the records.  How can I do this while remaining on the same page?

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
&nbsp;

        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Entry.aspx" runat="server" text="Add New Record" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="100%"
            Width="100%" onselectedindexchanged="grdView_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Prod_Id" HeaderText="product id " HeaderStyle-BackColor="Azure"  />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Prod_Name" HeaderText="Product Name" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Azure" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit_Price" HeaderText="Unit Price " HeaderStyle-BackColor="Azure" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="In_Hand" HeaderText="In Hand" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Azure" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fixed" HeaderText="Fixed" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Azure" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Azure" />
                 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Prod_Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="edit.aspx?Prod_Id={0}" Text="Edit" />
                <asp:ButtonField   ButtonType="Link"  Text="Delete" />        

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

> code behind part

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            binddata();
        }

        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;

        void binddata()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=PracticeDb; user id=sa; pwd=manager;");
            con.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Products", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            grdView.DataSource = ds;
            grdView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void grdView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var P_id = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Prod_Id"].ToString();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress; initial catalog=PracticeDb; user id=sa; pwd=manager;");
            con.Open();
            string qry = "DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE Prod_Id='" +P_id+ "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();


        }



    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793955/how-to-add-a-confirm-delete-option-in-asp-net-gridview

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19347/Add-column-for-delete-in-GridView-with-confirmatio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use row databound event to accomplish this task.

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnDel" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this Record?');""CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Prod_Id") %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

and in the rowdatabound event you can have

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
    {
        //incase you need the row index 
        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        int Prod_Id= Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        //followed by your code 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I add the linkbutton inside an itemtemplate? Thanks. Trying to accomplish here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372431/how-to-add-a-delete-record-column-to-an-existing-gridview

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Wow it has been a while since i answered this. Yes its obligatory that you put the linkbutton inside of an item template.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks for your response regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinkButton in GridView

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete"  runat="server" CommandName="delete" title="Delete"
OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you Want to Delete this Record?');"
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Prod_Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void grdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     int P_Id = e.CommandArgument;   \\ This will get the Product id in P_Id variable
     \\ do your delete code
 }
```

Comment: there is no linkButton option in Gridview

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get linkbutton using following code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=Quantity>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete"  runat="server" CommandName="delete" title="Delete"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you Want to Delete this Record?');"
    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Prod_Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And code behind use below code:

```
protected void grdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
if(e.CommandName == "delete")
 {

 int P_Id = e.CommandArgument;   \\ This will get the Product id in P_Id variable
 \\ do your delete code
  }
 }
```