# Dynamically adding Table rows

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add values in table rows on button click. It's working on database but not working on web page. It override on last row on page.

How can I generate new row on every button click.

here is my button click code--

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblAdd.Visible = false;
    Label1.Visible = false;

    //Label2.Visible = false;


}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
        I = Hidden1.Value;
        I += 1;
        cb1.ID = "cb1" + I;

        TableRow Table1Row = new TableRow();
        Table1Row.ID = "Table1Row" + I;
        TableCell RCell1 = new TableCell();
        RCell1.Controls.Add(cb1);
        TableCell RCell2 = new TableCell();
        RCell2.Text = txtName.Text;

        tblLanguagesRow.Cells.Add(RCell1);
        tblLanguagesRow.Cells.Add(RCell2);
        tblLanguages.Rows.Add(tblLanguagesRow);
        Hidden1.Value = I;

        btnAdd.Visible = true;
        btnDelete.Visible = true;
        Label2.Visible = true;
        Label2.Text = "Successfully Added";
        add();
    }
    txtName.Text = "";
}

public int add()
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("hrm_AddLanguages", sqlConnection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@IsDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Please Help me.

Comment: What code have in Page_Load ?

Comment: Added page_Load code.

Comment: Where do you fill the table? When the button is pressed create post-back and the page reloads. So logically your table should be empty. Am i wrong?

Comment: How to fill table. I know how to bind gridview. But how can I bind table.

Comment: any suggestion please !

Comment: Fill grid client side with ajax

Comment: using table.. not grid

Comment: Fill html table client side with ajax!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible try to do this using Grid view. It is better to use grid view instead of table.

Check out below link. It will help you to find your solution.

[DataTable in ASP.Net Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360564/datatable-in-asp-net-session/23361055#23361055)