# How to Dynamically add Table rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add values in table rows on button click. It's working on database but not working on web page. It override on last row on page.

How can I generate new row on every button click.

here is my button click code--

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tblAdd.Visible = false;
    Label1.Visible = false;

    //Label2.Visible = false;


}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 1;
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        TableRow NewRow1 = new TableRow();

        //1st cell
        TableCell NewCell1 = new TableCell();

        //new checkbox
        CheckBox newCheckBox1 = new CheckBox();


        // adding lebel into cell
        NewCell1.Controls.Add(newCheckBox1);

        // adding cells to row
        NewRow1.Cells.Add(NewCell1);

        //2ed cell
        TableCell NewCell2 = new TableCell();

        Label newLabel1 = new Label();
        count = count + 1;
        newLabel1.Text = txtName.Text;
        newLabel1.ID = "label" + count;

        NewCell2.Controls.Add(newLabel1);
        NewRow1.Cells.Add(NewCell2);

        //adding row into table
        tblLanguages.Rows.Add(NewRow1);

        btnAdd.Visible = true;
        btnDelete.Visible = true;
        Label2.Visible = true;
        Label2.Text = "Successfully Added";
        add();
    }
    txtName.Text = "";
}

public int add()
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("hrm_AddLanguages", sqlConnection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
    command.Parameters.Add("@IsDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible try to do this using Grid view. It is better to use grid view instead of table.

Check out below link. It will help you to find your solution.

[DataTable in ASP.Net Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360564/datatable-in-asp-net-session/23361055#23361055)