# How to fire datalist_ItemCommand in page load after postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datalist, itemcommand

Is it possible to fire `datalist_ItemCommand` function in page load after post back. It doesn't make sense but I need to achieve this.

Here is the scenerio: I have `datalist` control and it loaded with some person data. It has got a delete button in `itemTemplate`.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
      <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("EMail") %></td>
      <td align="center"><asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' OnClientClick="confirmMe('My Program title','Are you sure ?','Yes', 'No', 'datalist1_ItemCommand'); return false;"></asp:LinkButton></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

When delete button clicked, custom modal box showing and wait for user response. If user click yes in modal box then itemCommand function should be fired. That's why you see `datalist_ItemCommand` function in `OnClientClick` attribute.

Here is JS :

```
function confirmMe(title, content, button_ok, button_no, asp_control) {

    swal({
        title: title,
        text: content,
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#8dc63f",
        confirmButtonText: button_ok,
        cancelButtonText: button_no,
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: true
    },
    function (result) {

        if (result === true)
            __doPostBack(asp_control, '');
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you open modal from JS side? check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793955/how-to-add-a-confirm-delete-option-in-asp-net-gridview

Comment: Yes I open modal from JS. But this post show me browser native alertbox. I dont want use it.

Comment: Than you need something like this ? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238122/Delete-Functionality-in-GridView-with-Confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Just call _doPostBack with appropriate id when accepting from modal,
Example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238122/Delete-Functionality-in-GridView-with-Confirmation)

```
function deleteItem(uniqueID, itemID) {
    //Show dialog here
        //on accept call __doPostBack(uniqueID, ''); than close modal
        //on cancel close modal
    return false
}
```

and call this method on client click

```
OnClientClick="javascript:return deleteItem(this.name, this.alt);"
```